# Dagger + Otto architecture guidance

Tags: android, architecture, dagger, otto

I am trying to develop an app with a somewhat modular architecture (nobody knows about no one, but everybody still can communicate). I will begin with an example:

Inside the **`LoginFragment`:**

```
@OnClick
void login() {
    bus.post(new AuthorizeEvent(email, password)); // bus is a Bus from Otto
}

@Subscribe
public void onAuthorizedEvent(AuthEvent event) {
    // ... user was authorized
}
```

The **`Authenticator`** catches this event and then posts back:

```
@Subscribe
public void onAuthorizeEvent(AuthorizeEvent event) {
    // ... login
    bus.post(new AuthEvent(user));
}
```

`Authenticator` depends on a lot of stuff through Dagger:

```
@Inject
public Authenticator(ApiService apiService, Context context, Bus uiBus, Scheduler ioScheduler,
                     Scheduler uiScheduler) {
    this.apiService = apiService;
    this.context = context;
    this.uiBus = uiBus;
    this.ioScheduler = ioScheduler;
    this.uiScheduler = uiScheduler;

    uiBus.register(this);
}
```

which is provided by the `AuthModule`:

```
@Module(
    complete = false,
    library = true,
    includes = {
            ApiModule.class,
            ApplicationModule.class
    }
)
public class AuthModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Authenticator provideAuthenticator(ApiService apiService, @ForApplication Context context,
                                       @UIBus Bus uiBus, @IOScheduler Scheduler ioScheduler,
                                       @UIScheduler Scheduler uiScheduler) {
        return new Authenticator(apiService, context, uiBus, ioScheduler, uiScheduler);
    }
}
```

My `Application` class:

```
public class AbsApplication extends Application {
    private ObjectGraph graph;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        graph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules());
    }

    public Object[] getModules() {
        return new Object[]{
                new ApplicationModule(this),
                new ApiModule(),
                new AuthModule()
        };
    }

    public void inject(Object object) {
        graph.inject(object);
    }
}
```

---

**The question is** - where do I instantiate (`@Inject`) the `Authenticator`? I don't use it directly in any of my classes. Can it be a field in the `AbsApplication` class? Should I even use Dagger for the `Authenticator`? Am I not using `Dagger`'s modules properly?

---

I know that I can `@Inject Authenticator` inside the `LoginFragment`, but I am exploring new patterns. Bear with me, please.

Comment: Sorry, do you have all the source code available in github to explore? I have an Android Demo project but with Roboguice and Guice not dagger, maybe it can help you.

Comment: @NicolasJafelle nope, no GitHub project.